# Table Variable and NULLS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have run the below code but NULL do not show in the final query result.
 I can see that the NULL were inserted in the temp table. When I call the variable in the query, NULL values do not show up.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]; 
GO  

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET STATISTICS IO ON;  

DECLARE @values TABLE 
(     
 Value VARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)  

INSERT INTO @values 
VALUES (NULL), ('Black'), ('Blue'), ('Grey'), ('Multi'), ('Red'), ('Silver'), ('Silver'), ('Black'), ('White'), ('Yellow')  --SELECT Value FROM @values; 

SELECT Production.Product.Name, Production.Product.ProductNumber,   Production.Product.Color, Production.Product.ListPrice,   Production.Product.SIZE, Production.Product.[Weight],   Production.Product.ProductLine, Production.Product.Class,   Production.Product.STYLE, Production.ProductPhoto.ThumbNailPhoto,   Production.ProductPhoto.LargePhoto FROM Production.Product INNER JOIN Production.ProductProductPhoto   ON Production.Product.ProductID =     Production.ProductProductPhoto.ProductID   INNER JOIN Production.ProductPhoto   ON Production.ProductProductPhoto.ProductPhotoID =     Production.ProductPhoto.ProductPhotoID 
--BEGIN CALLOUT A 
WHERE --Production.Product.Color IS NOT NULL 
(Production.Product.Color IN (SELECT Value FROM @values)); 
--END CALLOUT A 
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

An `IN` statement will be executed identically to `(field = val1) OR (field = val2) OR (field = val3)`. Putting a `NULL` in there will boil down to `(field = NULL)`, which naturally won't work.

Instead of inserting a `NULL` into `@values`, try this:

```
WHERE (Production.Product.Color IN (SELECT Value FROM @values))
   OR (Production.Product.Color IS NULL)
```

Comment: small issue here. What if null is not inserted in the table variable ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk then don't add the `OR` part?

Comment: so change the sql when then contents of the table variable changes ? Interesting

Comment: @t-clausen.dk in my solution, there is never a `NULL` in the table. It looks like in the OP's case, he always wants to check for `NULL` values in `Color`. Which is why I believe my solution will work fine for him.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET STATISTICS IO ON;  

DECLARE @values TABLE 
(     
 Value VARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)  

INSERT INTO @values 
VALUES (NULL), ('Black'), ('Blue'), ('Grey'), ('Multi'), ('Red'), ('Silver'), ('Silver'), ('Black'), ('White'), ('Yellow')  --SELECT Value FROM @values; 

SELECT Production.Product.Name, Production.Product.ProductNumber,   Production.Product.Color, Production.Product.ListPrice,   Production.Product.SIZE, Production.Product.[Weight],   Production.Product.ProductLine, Production.Product.Class,   Production.Product.STYLE, Production.ProductPhoto.ThumbNailPhoto,   Production.ProductPhoto.LargePhoto 
FROM Production.Product 
INNER JOIN Production.ProductProductPhoto   ON Production.Product.ProductID =     Production.ProductProductPhoto.ProductID   
INNER JOIN Production.ProductPhoto   ON Production.ProductProductPhoto.ProductPhotoID =     Production.ProductPhoto.ProductPhotoID 
--BEGIN CALLOUT A 
WHERE --Production.Product.Color IS NOT NULL 
(ISNULL(Production.Product.Color,'EMPTY') IN (SELECT ISNULL(Value,'EMPTY') FROM @values)); 
--END CALLOUT A 
GO
```

Comment: Food for fought: answers should have some text to explain the code, or text only. Code only answers might help the OP, but for future readers will be harder to understand. (This is not a downvote, just a recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

Use [INTERSECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(INTERSECT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

```
WHERE 
  exists (SELECT Production.Product.Color INTERSECT SELECT Value FROM @values)
```